# Parsing of custom structure in Java

Tags: java, jaxb

I need to parse XML with JAXB which describes structure. E.g. it can be something like:

```
<structure name="s1">
 <integer value="15" name="i1" />
 <structure name="s1_1">
   <string value="hello" />
 </structure>
</structure>
```

As you can see, structures can be nested. So my questions are:

1. what is the best practices to represent such structure in Java
2. how can it be parsed using JAXB?

**UPD: Structure can contain several different items (integers, strings, float numbers, arrays/etc) and I can't make assumption about it contents. I just know possible types of  fields, but not their quantity or order.**

Comment: What have you tried so far? What kind of object model would you like?  Do you want different classes to represent `integer`, `string`, etc.  Is the order of elements significant?  Do you want the value of the integer element stored as an integer?

Comment: At the moment one of the possible solutions I consider is representing structure as list of fields, where field is an object which consists of it's type and values which can also be link to another list and so on. But I'm not sure about efficiency of such approach. Also there will be problems with accessing such structures in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
class Structure
{
    String name;
    Integer value;
    Structure child;
    // or 
    Set<Structure> children;
}
```

Parsing with JAXB pretty much reduces to using the JAXB tools on the class above and generate the appropriate stubs/proxies/whatever and feed appropriate XML into the marshaller - there are plenty examples on SO and elsewhere.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Create class `Structure`. Mark it using JAXB annotation:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "structure")
public class Structure {
    @XmlElement(name = "integer")
    private IntegerValue integer;
    @XmlElement(name = "string")
    private StringValue string;

    // add default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Create classes `IntegerValue` and `StringValue` that wrap int and string and use `@XmlAttribute`.

Now you are ready to use this with JAXB.

This is an example how to serialize your objects into XML:

```
Structure s = new Structure();
//...............
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.yourcompany.yourpackage");
ctx.createMarshaller().marshal(s, System.out);
```

To deserialize use `Unmarshaller`.